Flink Job design - working with hybrid Kafka topic
I have a kafka topic that contains few events types.(This is given)
The events are JSON documents.
Lets call the event types: A,B,C,D,E.
I can tell the type by using a field I have in each and every event.
I want to have a Flink job that will handle events A & B separately (using a session window), C & D should go to another type of window and event D should be dropped.
Can I implement such a design in Flink?
Thanks

If so, you could take advantage of Flink's support for Side Outputs and use that as a means to map each of the distinct types to its own stream and operate on those separately (or union them downstream, etc.)
Basically:

Read your data from a Kafka Topic (via KafkaSource)
Map/Process your data via side-outputs to get each specific type
Construct your job graph to align with what you need (union and window downstream, etc.)

This might look something like:
val events = streamEnv
  .fromSource(KafkaSource.build(...))
  .process(YourTypeSeparatorOperator())

// Example: Getting A & B events
val a = events.getSideOutput(Tags.a)
val b = events.getSideOutput(Tags.b)

// Union this stream (and act on it via windowing, etc.)
val ab = a.union(b)

// Likewise perform operations necessary for C & D types here

// Eventually merge all of these separate streams together if needed

In the above YourTypeSeparatorOperator() would actually use the side-outputs and based on the type of your event, output it to a designated side-output:
// Example OutputTag
object Tags{
    val a = OutputTag("a", TypeInformation.of(YourClass::class.java))
    val b = OutputTag("b", TypeInformation.of(YourClass::class.java))
    val c = OutputTag("c", TypeInformation.of(YourClass::class.java))
    val d = OutputTag("d", TypeInformation.of(YourClass::class.java))     
}

// Usage
override fun processElement(...) {
   ...
   when (message.type) {
      "a" -> context.output(Tags.a, message)
      "b" -> context.output(Tags.b, message)
      "c" -> context.output(Tags.c, message)
      "d" -> context.output(Tags.d, message)
   }
}


Thanks Rion. I will try this direction and update the post.

If you'd rather use the Table/SQL API, that's easily done. E.g.,
WITH use_session_windows AS
  (select * from events where events.type = 'a' or events.type = 'b')
SELECT window_start, window_end, count(*) AS cnt
  FROM TABLE(
    SESSION(DATA => TABLE use_session_windows,
            TIMECOL => DESCRIPTOR(rowtime),  
            GAP => INTERVAL '30' MINUTES))
  GROUP BY window_start, window_end;


